# Explorer.exe doesn't start?

Tags: vb.net, windows-explorer, kill-process

I used the following code in Visual Basic to kill and restart `explorer.exe`.

**TO KILL** `Explorer.exe` (Works Fine):

```
Dim process As System.Diagnostics.Process = Nothing
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
psi.UseShellExecute = True
psi.FileName = "taskkill.exe"
psi.Arguments = "/F /IM explorer.exe"
process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
```

**TO RESTART** `Explorer.exe` again:

I tried-

```
Shell("explorer.exe")
```

and

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe")
```

When I execute, it only opens an explorer window, but it doesn't start the `explorer.exe`  process. I am using `win 8.1`.

Comment: Maybe we could help solve the problem that the solution is to attempt to kill and restart explorer, rather than trying to fix your solution?

Comment: `It opens an explorer window, but doesn't start the explorer.exe process`? That doesn't make sense - if you are seeing an Explorer Window then explorer.exe must be running. What are your actual symptoms? Is your taskbar not visible? Is explorer.exe not visible in Task Manager? Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: As I understand it, he kills the `Shell` by killing the explorer.exe process. Then he want's to restart the `Shell` (explorer) but executing  `explorer.exe` only opens a window of the explorer instead of restarting the shell. - I think since Vista the Shell cannot be invoked by a user, or it has to be at least registered as `Shell` in the WindowsNT registry section. on how to restart the shell i'll have to do some research

Comment: Tell us: Did you mess with the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell` entry?

Comment: Also killing is so easy you can do it yourself... you don't need taskkill.exe to do the dirty work for you :)

Comment: You are correct!, that's my problem it only opens an explorer window . and i checked task manager but explorer.exe wasn't  there ,and the task bar doesn't appear also. @MrPaulch

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes Please , if you can give me a sample to kill and restart the Explorere.exe that would be great ! it can be java or vb.net .. thanks

Comment: @RB. yes the task bar isn't visible  and explorer.exe  isn't visible in the task manager section , but when i type exploere.exe in "run new task" then all comes to normal ...

Comment: No, I was trying to say that killing and restarting explorer probably **isn't** the right thing to do. For some reason, you think it's going to achieve `X` for you. If we knew what `X` was, we may be able to offer better suggestions to achieve it.

Comment: Look, have you checked the Registry value I asked you for? couse that would explain a lot...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  what i want to do is , i want to start a windows form ,user to fill it  before doing anything , simply,only after filling the form user should be able to use the PC

Comment: You may do better by trying to implement a [Credential Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163489.aspx). That's the hook that Windows (since Vista) offers to programmers who want to be involved in the login process. (But you won't be writing one in VB.Net)

Answer (score 1):

Use This to start the explorer process

```
Dim ExProcess = New Process()
ExProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
ExProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
ExProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\windows\explorer.exe"
ExProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath
ExProcess.Start()
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I was facing the same issue as OP and your solution works fine.